# What does this logic/circuit symbol mean

Tags: logic-gates, diagram

While browsing through the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega324PV-AVR-MCU-with-CIP-and-picopower-40002102A.pdf) of an ATMega324p description of a pin I noticed this symbol which looks like four diodes/triangles pointing at each other.

[image: example symbol]

So my question is what is it actually?

Answer (score 2):

It's a transmission gate or analogue switch:

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4243

The top connection should have an inversion bubble.

Comment: (+1) Worth mentioning is that the "inspiration" for this symbol comes from the *valve* symbol. The symbol shown in the question is the representation of two valves atop each other. An alternate symbol for a transmission gate is literally the valve symbol with control and negated control inputs. Wikipedia link that shows both symbols : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate

Comment: @VincenteCunha: Have another look at it. It's two triangular buffer symbols - one pointing left and one pointing right.

Comment: @VicenteCunha I agree with transistor. I haven't got a reference at hand, but I don't think that symbol stemmed from the "valve" mechanical symbol. It's kinda two bidirectional buffers in parallel activated by two out-of-phase logic signals. Not the most simple and intuitive symbol, though. Meh!

Comment: @Transistor Agreed, it definitely can be seen as two buffers. This interpretation also makes most sense if we consider only the electrical engineering context. But I would argue engineering areas borrow from each other, and in a "chicken and egg" argument, the concept of a valve came first to be (if we consider the history of technological development/needs). Hidraulic circuits and electrical circuits share some representation similarities, and the most notable one is that "triangles dictate flow direction", be it fluid or current.

Comment: Example: a check valve behaves similarly to a diode, allowing flow in only one direction. One of the acceptable symbols used for check valves is literally the diode symbol used in electrical engineering.

Comment: The bottom wire is the one with the inversion bubble in the OP.